# Reason of child node assignments after deletion from Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a point which i haven't understood while learning BST Deletion mechanism. Could you explain me why there is an assignment (p->rchild =, p->lchild =) each time the Delete(Node* p, int key) is called? Actually, I thought that the Delete(Node* p, int key) method just keeps returning without any mutation so the tree doesn't change.

And while i was looking for an explanation, i stumbled into this sentence :

> We have to make assignments after deletion else we will end up having
> duplicate nodes.

If you agree with this statement, could you please explain it to me?

```
Node* BST::Delete(Node *p, int key) {
    Node* q;
 
    if (p == nullptr){
        return nullptr;
    }
 
    if (p->lchild == nullptr && p->rchild == nullptr){
        if (p == root){
            root = nullptr;
        }
        delete p;
        return nullptr;
    }
 
    if (key < p->data){
        p->lchild = Delete(p->lchild, key);
    } else if (key > p->data){
        p->rchild = Delete(p->rchild, key);
    } else {
        if (Height(p->lchild) > Height(p->rchild)){
            q = InPre(p->lchild);
            p->data = q->data;
            p->lchild = Delete(p->lchild, q->data);
        } else {
            q = InSucc(p->rchild);
            p->data = q->data;
            p->rchild = Delete(p->rchild, q->data);
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `if (p->lchild == nullptr && p->rchild == nullptr)` looks like if you hit the end of the line, you obliterate the last node whether it matches the key or not.  Not sure if this is the behaviour you want or not, but I figure it's worth pointing out.

Comment: It is removing nodes, so it has to assign the inferior to the deleted node, and put it at current node child position (be it left or right), to replace the deleted node and maintain the tree.

Comment: Also you must maintain the balanced part of the BST.

Comment: @Manuel 
To my understanding, it doesn't remove any nodes but updates some of them while traversing from top to bottom. Once it reaches to the last node that has neither of left and right childs, then it deletes that node. Still not clear to me!

Comment: @Surt i havent pasted the whole code but the Height() method keeps comparing each time left and right height of a node and based on that calls the predecessor or successor methods to replace the node with the appropriate node.

Comment: @user4581301 thank u for your attention. U r definetely right!

Comment: @Manuel after rethinking, i guess i got your point. So you basically mean that the nodes will be returned as children nodes to their parents but at some point a node (that matches the key) will be deleted and this (nullptr) must be the new child of the parent whose child node was removed. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Deletion and rotation are two examples of operations that can change the root of a subtree. In a recursive algorithm that involves those those operations, you need to update the pointer of a parent node to its children after returning from the child function.

Comment: @turtle changing the root of the subtree takes place only in terms of value update, doesn't it? It means that the node address does not change but only the value. Therefore, i thought that it wouldn't make any difference for that part of the tree.

Comment: @turtle On the other hand if the right node is met to be deleted and it has many other subtrees below , then we will only replace the value of our target node to be deleted and after some such replacements through recursions, a leaf node's address space will be freed. And the parent of that leaf node must not point to a freed memory space, hence it (child node) must return (after getting deleted and assigned a nullptr value).
So can you please tell me if there are other cases where as you mentioned "the pointer of a parent node to its children needs to be updated?

Comment: This code is not correct. I agree with the mistake highlighted in the first comment above. So I don't see how answering the question will help. In the end the code is still wrong.

Comment: @trincot, the code does not belong to me either. From a udemy course i m learning stuff from. No reason to be obsessed with it, he was right and i agreed with him. Besides, it has nothing to do with my question!

Comment: Fair enough. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why there is an assignment (`p->rchild =`, `p->lchild =`) each time the `Delete(Node* p, int key)` is called?

If the data is found, then the goal is to have a tree that has one node less. The algorithm will uses a value-swapping mechanism to ensure that the node that will actually be removed, is always a leaf node. The deletion of a leaf node consists of two actions:

1. The removal from memory;
2. The update of its parent so that the child pointer that references this deleted node is set to a null pointer.

As the algorithm recurses right to that leaf node, it cannot set the null pointer to its parent, as there is at this stage no reference available to the parent node. For that the *caller* should do something, since the caller *does* have a reference to the parent.

So when the recursive traversal arrives at the leaf node, it needs to convey to the caller that this node should be detached. It does so by returning a null pointer, and the agreement is that the caller (whose current node `p` is the parent) should assign the returned pointer to relevant child pointer. That way the deleted node is really detached from the rest of the tree.

> Actually, I thought that the `Delete(Node* p, int key)` method just keeps returning without any mutation so the tree doesn't change.

Surely the tree must change somehow to have a node deleted from it. The change happens in the assignment to `p->lchild` or `p->rchild`

> I stumbled into this sentence :
>
> > We have to make assignments after deletion else we will end up having duplicate nodes.

This is true. Let's take an example tree:

```
                 7
                / \
               3   8
              / \   \
             1   5   9
            /   / \ 
           0   4   6
```

Now let's see what happens if we call `Delete(root, 3)`. `p` points to the node with value 7. We go to the left with a recursive call:

```
p->lchild = Delete(p->lchild, key);
```

In the recursive execution context, we get a new `p` which points to the node with value 3. This is the value we're looking for, so we get into the outer `else` block. As the heights of the subtrees below that node are equal, we get into the inner `else` block. There we assign:

```
q = InSucc(p->rchild);
```

This `q` will reference the node with value 4. And now a duplication happens. We copy the data from `q` to `p`. That comes down to deleting the value 3 from the tree:

```
p->data = q->data;
```

But now we have twice the value 4 in the tree.

```
                 7
                / \
               4*  8
              / \   \
             1   5   9
            /   / \ 
           0   4*  6
```

So the algorithm descends to the (right) child, and now seeks to delete the node with value 4 in that subtree:

```
p->rchild = Delete(p->rchild, q->data);
```

In this new recursive call we get a new `p` again, which now refers to the node with value 5. We move left -- this assignment will play an important role later:

```
p->lchild = Delete(p->lchild, key);
```

This final recursive call has a new `p` that refers to the node with value 4 -- the one we were looking for.

This time we end up in the `if` block that has the `delete`, because this node is a leaf node. The node is freed and a null pointer is returned to the caller. From here on we start backtracking up the tree.

So one level up, at the node with value 5, we get the return value from the recursive call (which is a null pointer) and assign it:

```
p->lchild = Delete(p->lchild, key);
```

This important assignment will detach the duplicate node (with value 4) from the tree. You can see that if this assignment would not have been made, there would still be a reference to that node with a duplicate value -- even though it is pointing to freed memory.

The tree is now in its final shape:

```
                 7
                / \
               4   8
              / \   \
             1   5   9
            /     \ 
           0       6
```

Backtracking will still continue, going back to the root. Also there assignments are made to some child pointers, but these will not change the tree, as in all these cases we had returned `return p;`, which was the original value of the caller's child pointer.

#### Bug

As mentioned in the comments, the code has a bug. When deleting a leaf node, it does not verify that this node has actually the value to delete. And so in case you call this method with a value that does not occur in the tree, you'll end up deleting a leaf node with another value. In the example tree above: if you were to call `Delete(root, 10)`, the node with value 9 will be deleted.

To correct this bug, move the following `if` block:

```
if (p->lchild == nullptr && p->rchild == nullptr){
```

... inside the outer `else` block, as the first statement there.

Comment: Though i had already understood the logic of how this functions thanks to previous comments, i appreciate your perfectly detailed explanation. Hope this will also help the people who got confused in this topic like me. Thank you!